# iphone iframe question

Tags: iphone

is it possible to add an iframe to an iphone web page. I tried adding a standard iframe with height and width 100% however when i use them to display them in the simulator from the local files i cant scroll even after setting scrolling to auto. IS this a limitation of the simulator or am i making a mistake somewhere. im using this code

```
 <iframe src ="http://moodle.acs.gr" width="100%" height="90%" scrolling="auto">
```

iframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have problems with an iPhone and iframes, and this is on a normal iPhone, not a similator. I don't think you can scroll within iframes at all on the iphone browser. You'll have to do things with the `<meta name="viewport"` or iframe width/height to get it to work